# How invalidate ReplacementSpan

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I have a custom implementation of ReplacementSpan (override onDraw method), I want to redraw it on animation, but my **invalidate** method call does not trigger onDraw.
This is because the `TextDisplayList` does not change and `hadwareAccelerated was` enabled.

**How to fix it?! Maybe there is a solution through reflection?**

`setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE)` method call not suitable

Disable hardware acceleration also not suitable...

Comment: So, is it working with enable hardware acceleration?

Comment: @Style-7 No, if hardware acceleration enabled invalidate does not trigger onDraw,

Comment: What is the base class of ReplacementSpan?

Comment: You have to pass "notify changed" to span adapter.

Comment: @Style-7 What is span adapter? TextView doesn't have It

Comment: public your code